# firefox javascript: urls cause page redirects?

Tags: javascript, firefox

In most browsers if you enter `javascript:$('element').css('property', 'value');`

will result in the javascript code being run.

In firefox this will cause the page to change to a blank white page with [object] [object]

why is this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because Firefox shows the return value of that function. Add `void(0);` after it to avoid a page redirect. Example:

```
javascript:$('element').css('property', 'value');void(0);
```

My preffered way to run code in URLs:

```
javascript:void(function(){ /*code here*/ })();
```

In this way, you don't mess with the global namespace:

```
javascript:var y=1;alert(y);void(0);
```

Here, `window.y` contains now `1`, whereas `window.y` is `undefined` below:

```
javascript:void(function(){var y=1;alert)y)})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add:

```
void(0);
```

at the end.